Should application-services expose implementation details in errors?
Suppose I have a service-function like UserService.createUser. Within this function we might do some things that are not obvious to the caller of the function, for example the function needs to fetch the weather from an api, as we have a field on our user like "weatherWhenCreated". Now, if this request to the weather-api returns an error, should our service return a WeatherApiError, or simply just return an UnexpectedError?
So, should the service return all kinds of errors that it could encounter, or should it convert those error so they only make sense from the perspective from the caller? For example if I personally encounter a createUser-function, I dont know that it tries to reach a WeatherApi, and therefore that error might not make sense for me as a caller. But at the same time, I would lose details about the error if it only returned UnexpectedError.
